# Questions on de Branges' work on the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_de_Branges_de_Bourcia), Louis de Branges de Bourcia has obtained some notable
results, such as a proof of the [Bieberbach conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Branges%27s_theorem) in 1985, which is now
known as de Branges' theorem. Initially, his proof of this result was not accepted
to be correct. De Branges also claimed to have found a proof of the Riemann hypothesis
in 2004. The most recent version of this work dates from 2012.

1. Which methods does de Branges use in his purported proof of the
    Riemann hypothesis, and which are his key ideas?
2. Which precisely are the flaws in de Branges' work, and why is it thought
    that these flaws cannot be repaired in any straightforward way?
3. Does de Branges' work also have some significant value independent of
    whether it constitutes or contributes to a proof of the Riemann hypothesis?
4. Which materials would one have to read as a non-specialist in order
    to understand de Branges' work?

Comment: For some reasons why it won't work, read starting from the third paragraph here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_de_Branges_de_Bourcia#Work

Comment: i have read that.what i want is a more detailed explanation why the analytic tools are thought insufficient

Comment: This previous question is similar: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38049/

Comment: You can read the latest version of his paper and judge yourself: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~branges/site//Papers

Comment: Good example of improving a bad question.

Comment: As Alex R and Dan Petersen have pointed out there is some information on this already on MO, and on Wikipedia.  One could also look at this paper by Lagarias: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/debranges-houches.pdf  .

Comment: @darij: That's not a bad question! It's just a simple, natural one, and we'll interested in the precise answer, right. (I mean non-specialists)

Comment: The most recent version of de Branges's work on the proof of Riemann Hypothesis dates from 2016 and it can be found [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwiqXe8o_SAhWMqI8KHVmzCQQQFgg0MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.purdue.edu%2F~branges%2Fproof-riemann.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGgjLAwcBFWG5yfJ4DcW7rpXtT9Mw).